# Image button change to press state when click item in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

I have a list view with customize item, item in list view include: text view and image button, i have set background for image button with a selector. My problem is when i click on item in list view, image button change state to press (click event not trigger), i don't want to this, i want to image button change state to press only when i press on it. Any solution for me? Thanks!

Layout of item row

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/song_list_selector" >

        <ToggleButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textOn="@string/favorite"
            android:textOff="@string/favorite"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_toggle_button"
            android:id="@+id/toggle_favorite"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <ToggleButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_toggle_button"
            android:textOn="@string/offline"
            android:textOff="@string/online"
            android:id="@+id/toggle_offline"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_song_menu"
            android:contentDescription="@string/song_menu"
            android:id="@+id/btn_song_menu"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/toggle_favorite"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_song_menu"
            android:text="999 Doa Hong"
            android:textColor="#0e7491"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/lbl_song_name"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Nhac chi chuyen xua, da xa roi nhu giac mo..."
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/lbl_song_name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_song_menu"
            android:id="@+id/lbl_song_lyric"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_microphone"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="1,478"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/lbl_song_lyric"
            android:id="@+id/lbl_sing_times"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_save"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="548"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/lbl_song_lyric"
            android:id="@+id/lbl_save_times"/>

   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SongListActivity" >

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:id="@+id/list_song"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_no_song"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#b6b6b6"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would help us to see some code...otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I have been added list item xml

Comment: @DuHuynh could you show layout for listview?

Comment: @Chansuk, i have been added layout of listview

Comment: Remove 'android:focusable="false"' at your ImageButton, and add it to your ListView. Maybe it help your problem.

Comment: Still not showing the relevant java code.

Comment: Thanks @Chansuk but still not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As a default, ListView consume all the touch events and just propagate the duplicated status to its children. In order to avoiding this you should set focusable attribute as 'false' in ListView.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to focusability of ImageButton in listitem layout.

Add below line to root layout of your ListView's Item layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```